# SQLPLUS (Oracle) - Get MAX COUNT of GROUPBY

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, subquery, having

I need to identify which Month has the most entries. Ive used the TO_DATE function to format the date column to just the MONTH. Also, SELECT COUNT(*) in combination with the GROUP BY Clause I am able to return all records month and count attributes.

However, I need to be able to only return one row that is the MAX of the COUNT. IVE atempted to do so by adding a HAVING clause but returns an error. I suspect I need a subquery in here somewhere but am unsure as to how to go about it.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(P.DATEREGISTERED,'MONTH') MONTH, COUNT(*) COUNT
FROM PET P
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(P.DATEREGISTERED,'MONTH')
HAVING COUNT = MAX(COUNT);
```

Another Attempt:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(P.DATEREGISTERED,'MONTH') MONTH, COUNT(*) COUNT
FROM PET P
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(P.DATEREGISTERED,'MONTH')
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT MAX(TO_CHAR(P.DATEREGISTERED,'MONTH')) FROM PET P);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the query with alias, you are grouping by Month and getting a count of the number of records and you are checking whether that count is same as the maximum of the "date value" converted to month string. They are not even comparisons of the same type.

The query that you have provided in the answer correctly compares the count on both sides.

Another way to rewrite the query would be

```
select * from 
(SELECT TO_CHAR(P.DATEREGISTERED,'MONTH') MONTH, COUNT(*) COUNT
FROM PET P
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(P.DATEREGISTERED,'MONTH') order by count(*) desc )
where rownum=1
```

Here we order the records in the subquery by descending order of the count and then getting the first row from that.

Answer (score 0):

The bellow code works and returns the correct response. It is unclear to me as to why it works but the above attempts (w/ aliases) do not.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(P.DATEREGISTERED,'MONTH') MONTH, COUNT(*) COUNT
FROM PET P
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(P.DATEREGISTERED,'MONTH')
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT MAX(COUNT(*)) FROM PET P GROUP BY TO_CHAR(P.DATEREGISTERED,'MONTH'));
```

Comment: No, it only works where each month has a different count. OTOH the answer by cableload will always return a single row and, with only one table reference should be much more efficient.